# rails ELF file OS ABI invalid on server linux server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, server, elf, abi

I have problems with my rails application, when trying to run rake db:migrate on server (or rails c for example) im getting this stack trace:

> rake aborted!
>       LoadError: /home/users/ruby/.gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.2/v8/init.so: ELF file OS ABI invalid - /home/users/ruby/.gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/therubyracer-0.12.2/v8/init.so
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:4:in `require'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/v8.rb:4:in`'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/therubyracer.rb:1:in `require'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/therubyracer-0.12.2/lib/therubyracer.rb:1:in`'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `require'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in`block (2 levels) in require'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in `each'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in`block in require'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in `each'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in`require'
>       /home/users/ruby/.gems/gems/bundler-1.9.4/lib/bundler.rb:134:in `require'
>       /home/users/ruby/public_html/uvindex/config/application.rb:7:in`'
>       /home/users/ruby/public_html/uvindex/Rakefile:4:in `'

uname -a:

> Linux 68798.v.tld.pl 3.10.63.core2.37 #1 SMP Thu Dec 18 15:25:17 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: possible duplicate of [glibc: elf file OS ABI invalid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647818/glibc-elf-file-os-abi-invalid)

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing Rails enviornment while running migration.

```
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV= <your rails env>
```

Comment: done RAILS_ENV=production while ago, didnt worked :( . Thanks for support by the way :)