# /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, appium, libstdc++

I am trying to run appium tests. However I get error saying what:

```
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found
```

I am using RedHat6.6. When I run:

```
strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
```

I get this:

```
GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Is it possible to get GLIBCXX_3.4.15 for RedHat6.6?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that your `libstdc++.so.6` is too old for your program, You can try to update you `libstdc++.so`. In my `centos7`, my `libstdc++.so.6` is linked to `libstdc++.so.6.0.19`

```
libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

There are the strings in it

```
[root]#strings libstdc++.so.6|grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Maybe you could download a newer version and relink the `libstdc++.so.6`, but you should care about are other programs in you system still work well.

Update this lib you should vary careful, It may take new problems, I had replaced the `libc.so.6`, then all commands can't work, I used `/sbin/sln` fix it. See [glibc: elf file OS ABI invalid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7647818/glibc-elf-file-os-abi-invalid)

---

Download libstdc++ from [pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/fedora-21/fedora-x86_64/libstdc++-4.9.2-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm.html), then unpack it.

```
rpm2cpio libstdc++-4.9.2-1.fc21.x86_64.rpm |cpio -idmv
cp ./usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.20 /usr/lib64
```

Maybe you can use `LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.20` before you execute your program. Like this

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.20 ls -hl
```

Or `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.20`, but I'm not certain it will work.

If you relink the `libstdc++.so.6`, be careful.

Comment: These links are dead. :(   ... but it's a very useful answer. I like the rpm2cpio trick. And the LD_PRELOAD trick.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to `\node_modules\electron\dist` and Paste all the required Libraries there that will keep you safe from bricking your system

if you get undefined g_bytes ref error

Then Download https://jlison.github.io/bin/centos6/soichih/mirror/gcc-4.7.2.tar.gz and extarct it to some folder and update LD_LIBRARY_PATH
glibpath=/opt/glib/ (path where you have extracted glib )

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/glib-2.49.4-kgesagxmtbemim2denf65on4iixy3miy/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/libffi-3.2.1-wk2luzhfdpbievnqqtu24pi774esyqye/lib64:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/pcre-8.39-itdbuzevbtzqeqrvna47wstwczud67wx/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$glibpath/gettext-0.19.8.1-aoweyaoufujdlobl7dphb2gdrhuhikil/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score -2):

Replace your libstdc++.so.6 file with a new one, which includes GLIBCXX_3.4.15