# libstdc++.so.6: version not found - NO admin rights

Tags: linux, unix, gcc, remote-server, libstdc++

I am trying to run an executable file - SaTScanBatch, executable of the SaTScan software - on a remote machine from the terminal.

Here is the error I get

`/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version 'GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found`

The problem is similar to these:
[/usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216399/usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) or [How to fix: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386651/how-to-fix-usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) or [/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525271/usr-lib64-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

What is different in my case is that I do not have admin rights, so I cannot add libraries in usr/lib file. I downloaded libstdc++.6.0.15 in my remote repository, and I want to use it to execute my file.

Here are the possibilities I tried

i) Modify environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_RUN_PATH or LD_PRELOAD to the path of libstdc++.so.6.0.15.
--> Did not change anything

ii) Include the library in a static way

```
gcc SaTScanBatch -static-libstdc++
```

--> -static option is not recognized, I guess the remote machine's GCC version is too old.

iii) Try to link the file to the additional library:

```
gcc SaTScanBatch -L /path/library -l stdc++
```

or similarly

```
gcc SaTScanBatch -Wl,-rpath,path/to/library
```

--> Error

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: Cannot create .eh_frame_hdr section, --eh-frame-hdr ignored.
/usr/bin/ld: error in SaTScanBatch64(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.4.6/../../../../lib64/crt1.o: In function _start:
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to "main"
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

iv) Use PatchElf to link the file and the library --> I cannot install PatchElf because no admin rights

Thank you for any suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

> Modify environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH or LD_RUN_PATH or LD_PRELOAD to the path of libstdc++.so.6.0.15. --> Did not change anything

What exactly did you try?

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should be set to the directory containing the new `libstdc++.so.6` not the the file itself, and you need to `export` the environment variable so it's available to child processes, not just to your shell. And you need a symlink from `libstdc++.so.6` to `libstdc++.so.6.0.15` because the dynamic loader is going to look for that name, not `libstdc++.so.6.0.15`

`LD_RUN_PATH` is used *during linking* to bake a path into the executable. It does nothing at run-time when trying to run the executable. If you use it you need to set it to the directory that will contain the `libstdc++.so.6` file *on the remote machine*. Again, it needs to be set to a directory, not the path of the file.

`LD_PRELOAD` is something different again, and almost certainly not what you want. You would use it to force a particular shared library to be loaded before anything else when the executable runs. That can be used to pre-load a newer libstdc++ but it's usually better to use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to set a path at run-time or `LD_RUN_PATH` to set a path at link-time.

> Try to link the file to the additional library:

The commands you showed are nonsense, they don't include any objects in the link, so you're trying to create an executable out of nothing. That's why you get the error `undefined reference to "main"`

For your scenario I would recommend using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.