# GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found on CentOS 7

Tags: gcc, centos, libstdc++

I recently updated my gcc version on CentOS from 4.7 to 5.4, but now I am getting the following error when I compile my program

```
/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found
```

I found some [solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525271/usr-lib64-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found) , but I am still not able to fix the issue. These are the paths I found with `whereis gcc`

```
gcc: /usr/bin/gcc /usr/lib/gcc /usr/local/bin/gcc /usr/local/lib/gcc /usr/libexec/gcc /usr/share/man/man1/gcc.1.gz
```

and used this [libstdc](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/centos-x86_64/libstdc++-4.8.5-11.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) package for CentOS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version \`GLIBCXX\_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31525271/usr-lib64-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found)

Answer (score 44):

Try `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64`

Comment: References: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dynamic_or_shared.html#manual.intro.using.linkage.dynamic and https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/faq.html#faq.how_to_set_paths

Comment: Can you please post what errors are you getting? or try `unset LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Comment: This worked for me in a scientific linux container (Somehow library paths were not set)

Answer (score 7):

Maybe for someone it will be helpful:
I installed devtoolset-7 but there was no GLIBCXX_3.4.21, and maximum version was GLIBCXX_3.4.19. Long time I was looking for the solution. What worked for me: I cloned gcc 7.3 repo, made build and install. Then copied libstdc++.so.6 and libstdc++.so.6.0.24 to devtools-7, lib64 folder and it became work.

Comment: I moved the files to the /lib64 folder. But now I get a different strange error:
`Cannot get symbol ucol_setMaxVariable_50 from libicui18n
Error: /lib64/libicui18n.so.50: undefined symbol: ucol_setMaxVariable_50`

Answer (score 4):

I didn't have sudo access to my CentOS machine, so I installed gcc with conda. If you installed gcc with conda the above answer won't work. 
check your gcc installation path as:

`$ which gcc`

output:
`/home/ags/miniconda3/envs/GE/bin/gcc`

This tells that gcc is installed in `GE` conda environment, now export LD_LIBRARY_PATH as the path to `lib` directory this environment.

`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/ags/miniconda3/envs/GE/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Simply your `libstdc++.so.6` not including `GLIBCXX_3.4.21`, so you need to replace that library.

When I examine `libstdc++.so.6.0.28` with `strings libstdc++.so.6.0.28 | grep GLIBCXX` the output is:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBCXX_3.4.26
GLIBCXX_3.4.27
GLIBCXX_3.4.28
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

So recreate symbolic with `libstdc++.so.6.0.28` will fix your problem (also fixed my problem ;)).

Answer (score 2):

find your gcc installed location and update LD_LIBRARY_PATH

for example

1. /usr/local/gcc/7.2.0/
2. setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/gcc/7.2.0/lib64/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Answer (score 1):

### 1. prepare

```
sudo yum provides libstdc++.so.6
```

### 2. download new version libstdc.so

> NOTICE: Since I need version 3.4.22+, so I can just update it to 3.4.26. Other versions are the same.

```
cd /usr/local/lib64
sudo wget http://www.vuln.cn/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/libstdc.so_.6.0.26.zip
unzip libstdc.so_.6.0.26.zip
cp libstdc++.so.6.0.26 /usr/lib64
cd /usr/lib64
```

### 3. Check the soft link version of libstdc++.so.6

```
ls -l | grep libstdc++
```

It may shows like this:

```
libstdc++.so.6 ->libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

### 4. Remove /usr/lib64 original link libstdc++.so.6, you can backup it before remove.

```
sudo rm libstdc++.so.6
```

then, relink it.

```
sudo ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.26 libstdc++.so.6
```

OK, check the newest link

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

It may shows like this:

> GLIBCXX_3.4
>
> …
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.25
>
> GLIBCXX_3.4.26
>
> GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH

Done!