# R reticulate libstdc++so GLIBCXX_3.4.21 not found issue

Tags: python, r, conda, reticulate

I was trying to use pandas from R . I used the reticulate library for the same.  The sample code I used is given below

`library(reticulate)
use_condaenv("my_env_37",required=T)
py_discover_config()
py_run_string("import pandas as pd")`

Error

```
> py_run_string("import pandas as pd")
Error in py_run_string_impl(code, local, convert) :
  ImportError: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by /opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/_libs/window.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)

Detailed traceback:
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from pandas.core.api import *
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/api.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby import Grouper
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pandas.core.groupby.groupby import GroupBy  # noqa: F401
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py", line 37, in <module>
    from pandas.core.frame import DataFrame
  File "/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/python3.6/si
Calls: py_run_string -> py_run_string_impl
Execution halted
```

Output from `py_discover_config()`

```
> py_discover_config()
python:         /opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/bin/python
libpython:      /opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/libpython3.6m.so
pythonhome:     /opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37:/opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37
version:        3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 30 2018, 01:22:34)  [GCC 7.3.0]
numpy:          /opt/anaconda/envs/my_env_37/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.16.2

NOTE: Python version was forced by use_python function
```

Conda version : `4.6.8`
Python Version : `3.6.8`
Pandas Version : `0.24.2`
OS: `RHEL 7.4`
R Version : `3.5.1`
reticulate Version : `1.9`

Is there any other configuration we have to use for getting this working. When I run the same pandas import from Python alone it is working as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your GCC is too old to be used with your R module. [This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44205687/glibcxx-3-4-21-not-found-on-centos-7) is not related to R but the error message is the same.

Do you have several installations of GCC (in particular in /usr/local)? If so, you can try something like `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib64:/usr/lib64` as suggested in the previous link I gave.

Otherwise, you should install a newer version of GCC (in a module environment if you still need your current version of GCC, see [here](http://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/Environment-Modules) for details, the explanations are very clear IMHO). Then, you will need to run R with your new environment.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Let me try the same and update.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue in a GitHub Action, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73101774/3820738) finally help me after [many trials](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/pmlb/pull/164). Essentially, I added the following as a step in my .github/workflows/pythonapp.yml file:

```
conda install -c conda-forge libstdcxx-ng
sudo rm /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
sudo ln -s /home/runner/.local/share/r-miniconda/pkgs/libstdcxx-ng-12.1.0-ha89aaad_16/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.30 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6
```

### Explanation

My initial error was:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
  ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.30' not found (required by /home/runner/.local/share/r-miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scipy/optimize/_highs/_highs_wrapper.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so)
```

so I needed to remove the existing libstdc++.so.6 and make a symlink for it in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/.

`find / -name "libstdc++.so*"` showed me where my libstdc++.so.6.0.30 file was, so then the last step was to point the symlink there.